# finding a string among several zipped files (webapps)

Tags: linux, tomcat, grep, zip

We have to find a string, let's say "foobar" among several webapps.

However, some webapps contain zipped files, eg log4j.jar.

Therefore, grep -IR "foobar" /pathto/tomcatroot/ won't work, because of compressed files.

unzip -c /pathto/tomcatroot/libdir/log4j.jar |grep foobar can solve the problem, but only for one file

Is there a way to achieve this for a whole directory?

Answer (score 1):

For a jar file you can try this:

```
for i in *.jar; do jar -tvf "$i" | grep  yourstring && echo "$i"; done
```

For zip files you can try zcat or zgrep

```
zcat yourfile.zip |grep string
```